# ngFor Not display array data, this data retrieve form Firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hey I know this question comes up a lot but the normal fixes do not work.

ts

```
onChangeFormType(changeFormType) {
this.serverData.getData('questionnaire/' + changeFormType)
  .subscribe(
    (response: Response) => {
      this.formType = response.json();
      let key = Object.keys(this.formType);
      for (let i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
        this.currentValue.push(this.formType[key[i]])
      }
      console.log('current Value', this.currentValue);
    },
    (error) => console.log('Form Error', error)
  )}
```

In `console.log('current Value', this.currentValue);` works good.

But, when I run ngFor loop in DOM it does not work.

[image]

html

```
<div class="col-9" *ngFor="let data of currentValue">
  <div formGroupName="questions">
    <div class="form-Group">{{ data.sno }}</div>
      <br>
      <div class="from-Group">{{ data.question}}</div>
    </div>
  <div formGroupName="options">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" formControlName="op1">{{ data.options}}
    </label></div>
```

Comment: What's the output of `console.log` ?

Comment: what does console.log('current Value', this.currentValue); return?

Comment: current Value 
[{…}]
0
:
formType
:
""
items
:
Array(1)
0
:
{options: {…}, question: "Test Msg", sno: 1}
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)
__proto__
:
Object
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)
console output

Comment: The elements in your area to don't seem to have the properties you are looking for in the html

Comment: now how I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `options`, `question` and `sno` properties are properties of the elements in the `items`-array of each `data`-object. Therefore you can nest another `*ngFor` inside the one you have. Like this:

```
<div class="col-9" *ngFor="let data of currentValue">
  <div *ngFor="let item of data.items">
    <div formGroupName="questions">
      <div class="form-Group">{{ item.sno }}</div>
        <br>
        <div class="from-Group">{{ item.question }}</div>
      </div>
    <div formGroupName="options">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" formControlName="op1">{{ item.options }}
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Allthough `item.options` is an object you might want to handle that another way depending on how it is structured.